# PSObject & sorting

Tags: powershell

the file ip.txt a list of IP adress

```
function CreateObj
{
    param([string]$IP,[string]$class,[int]$number)
    $Obj=New-Object PSObject
    $Obj | Add-Member -Name IP -MemberType NoteProperty  -Value $IP  
    $Obj | Add-Member -Name CLASS -MemberType NoteProperty  -Value $Class  
    $Obj | Add-Member -Name NUMBER -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $number 
    return $Obj
}  


$allip = get-content ip.txt

$tab=@()
foreach ($item in $allip)
{
    $class = $item.substring(0,$item.lastindexof("."))
    $number = [int]($item.substring($item.lastindexof(".")+1))
    $tab += createobj $item $Class $number
}
$tab | sort |get-unique # <-- this fail problem of type i think ?
```

$tab | sort |get-unique # <-- this fail... problem of type ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the -unique parameter of sort-object cmdlet :
`$tab | sort IP -unique`

Comment: it's change nothing to my problem the sort doesn't work i need $tab | %{ [int]$_.number }|sort that suck... )

Comment: I'm not a wizzard and cannot guess what result do you expect and what error do you get...

Comment: its can't be sorted because "number" are not [int] type so i got random result

Comment: Kayasax is trying to tell you that you cannot get unique values from an unsorted list. What is the unique value you are trying to sort on. It does not matter if it is `[int]` or not. You can sort on lots of things. you should show some sample output and desired output.

Comment: i dont understand why u said that i can't do a get-unique ..?
its works on get-process | get-unique, with my script its return me only 1 lines ..?